# Cell change not automatically detected

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using the following script to keep a google spreadsheet automatically sorted:

https://gist.github.com/mikebranski/285b60aa5ec3da8638e5

It works like a charm, but . . .

If 'SORT_COLUMN_INDEX' is in anyway the result of a formula, changes are not detected and the spreadsheet gets not (re)sorted. I can trigger the sorting function by editing the formula (netto not changing anything) but I would like to avoid this action.

So when I type numbers in 'SORT_COLUMN_INDEX' or produce them with a formula the sorting function works. But when the formula's automatically do their work (producing numbers in the column), it does not work.

Anyone for an idea on this?

André

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the script so that it also re-sorts when  changes are made to the cells referenced by the formula. If those cells are in a column with `ANOTHER_COLUMN_INDEX`, that means replacing (lines 99-101)

```
if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}
```

with

```
if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX || editedCell.getColumn() == ANOTHER_COLUMN_INDEX) {
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}
```

or, better, create an array `WATCHED_COLUMNS` with column numbers to watch, and check using

```
if (WATCHED_COLUMNS.indexOf(editedCell.getColumn() != -1) {
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}
```